# Duda sobre índices en una tabla tipo calendario en MySQL e InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Tengo algunas dudas con una tabla en MySQL con el engine InnoDb que va a manejar un calendario y otros valores.

Este es el estado actual del `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `liturgia_calendario` (
  `id_calendario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `today` date NOT NULL,
  `weekDay` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7') COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_liturgia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_liturgia` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cal_time` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_calendario`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uqx_liturgia_calendario` (`today`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1024 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

Mis dudas son:

1. La tabla va a guardar las fechas de cada día en la columna `today`, y no puede haber dos fechas iguales. ¿En ese caso `today` puede hacer de llave primaria? ¿Por qué? O, ¿debo conservar `id_calendario` como llave primaria y por qué? ¿Tiene sentido realmente un incremental para una tabla como esta?
2. Como se puede ver `today` tiene una restricción `UNIQUE`. Supongo que si decido  hacer a `today` llave primaria esa restricción ya no tendría sentido, para fines de unicidad por supuesto que no, pero ¿tampoco para fines de indexación? ¿por qué? Como dato, `today` no se va a relacionar con ninguna tabla, simplemente el usuario va a poner una fecha y a partir de ella voy a traer contenido de otras tablas por las columnas indicadas en el punto 3.
3. Voy a usar las columnas `weekDay`, `id_liturgia` y `pre` para obtener datos de otras tablas. ¿Debo crear índices en esas columnas?
4. En la columna `weekDay` necesito guardar el número de día de la semana. Esto es porque debo tomar el contenido en cierta tabla según el día de la semana, pero ese día no es siempre el real. O sea, hay situaciones en las que un lunes debo tomar el contenido del domingo. Mi duda con respecto a esa columna es si el `COLLATE` tiene sentido ahí, siendo que solamente voy a guardar valores el 1 al 7.

Perdonen la batería de preguntas, estuve leyendo [aquí](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/10/how-innodb-promotes-unique-constraints/), pero no termino de aclararme.

Comment: Si puede ser una `clave primaria` al ser `unica`. En este caso es una `clave candidata` ya que tienes un `id autoincremental`. La `clave primaria` debería de ser la mejor clave para identificar esa tabla. Entonces, esto puede acabar en un debate por opiniones. ¿Es `today` la mejor clave?

Answer (score 3):

Intentaré responder de manera objetiva, porque no hay una única opción correcta y la pregunta podría ser votada como basada en opiniones. Por tanto me limitaré a los hechos para darte en qué pensar y elijas lo que te parezca más cómodo:

#### 1. `today`como clave primaria

Nada te impide usar una fecha como clave primaria si sabes que va ser única. Internamente es probable que MySQL la guarde como un número entero (UNIX time o similar), así que el rendimiento no debería variar respecto a usar un autoincremental.

#### 2. UNIQUE y/o PRIMARY KEY

Una clave primaria es por definición única, así que la restricción UNIQUE está implícita en la restricción PRIMARY KEY. La mayoría de los sistemas gestores de bases de datos relacionales (RDMS en inglés) indexan automáticamente las claves primarias.

#### 3. Relación con otras tablas

Los campos que uses para buscar en otras tablas no tienen porqué estar indexados en esta tabla, sino en las tablas donde vas a buscar por ellos. De todos modos esto no es necesario a menos que vayas a tener muchos registros en dichas tablas (el rendimiento para unos pocos miles de registros no se ve afectado, pero si trabajas con cientos de miles si se notará la falta de índices).

#### 4. `weekday`

Me falta contexto. Es posible que el campo sea redundante porque puedes obtenerlo directamente del campo `today`, pero si prefieres tener este dato por separado para simplificar las operaciones porque lo vas a usar mucho, es también correcto.

Quizá deberías guardar más valores que te simplifiquen la lógica: del 1 al 7 para los días de la semana y 0 (u 8) para indicar el fin de semana. También podrías usar valores como `'71'` para indicar "domingo + lunes"... como dije antes, dependerá de los casos de uso.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, creo que los puntos `1` y `2` quedan del todo claros con tu respuesta. En el punto `3` las relaciones con otras tablas podrían ascender a unos pocos miles de registros, realmente `id_liturgia` es un punto de entrada a una tabla que a su vez se relaciona con otras, hablamos de unas 10 tablas inter-relacionadas. Otro asunto aquí es el contexto, las tablas son solicitadas por contextos diferentes (página web, aplicación móvil, API) y con una cantidad de usuarios que tiende a aumentar con el tiempo. En el punto 4 sólo necesito números del `1` al `7`...

Comment: ... No necesito más, sólo que hay días que aunque sea lunes o martes necesito tomar los valores del día `1` o de otro día.

Answer (score 2):

1. yo personalmente conservaría el id, aunque puede ser llave primaria al ser única. Personalmente, yo conservaría el id como llave primaria, el incremental es útil a la hora de ver qué records se han guardado antes. Y luego también porque no sé qué otro código hay. Ante la duda, yo no lo cambio.
2. si decides hacer today como llave primaria, yo mantendría la restricción, por si acaso. Si today no se relaciona con ninguna tabla deja el id como llave, las fechas son más difíciles de indexar. Además, date cuenta que dos fechas no van a ser iguales, porque es prácticamente imposible, salvo que descartes la hora, entonces puedes tener problemas.
3. no es necesario.
4. no lo puedes hacer con today? digo, usando alguna que otra función

Sin saber el uso, mis respuestas son conjeturas basadas en experiencia.

Ten en cuenta si es posible que por algún motivo, estos principios cambien y today ya no sea único, así que por seguridad yo dejaría el id

Comment: No son malas elecciones, pero si te fijas has escrito varias veces *"Personalmente"* y *"yo haría..."*. Éste es el peligro de esta pregunta: es opinable.

Comment: como ya he dicho, me falta saber el uso de la tabla

Comment: Gracias. (1) En el diseño lo importante son las fechas. Luego de la respuesta de Pablo me queda más claro que el id serviría de poco. (2) Sólo interesan las fechas, no las horas, de hecho el campo es de tipo `date`. (3) OK en ese punto que era quizá el que menos claro tenía. (4) No. En la pregunta creo que lo explico. En muchos casos podría usar `today` para saber el día de la semana, pero hay casos en que, aunque el día de la semana sea `2, 3, 4...` debo tener en `weekDay` otro valor, `1` o `7` según el caso. La cuestión va sobre liturgia y hay días de semana que deben tratarse como domingo.